# Why can't I navigate from a route that defines a component for a named outlet to a child route that defines a new component for the named outlet?

Tags: angular

I am having issues navigating from a route (i.e. `/clients`) with an auxiliary outlet component defined to a child route (i.e. `/clients/1`) with a different auxiliary outlet component defined.

`admin/admin-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    outlet: 'aux',
    component: AdminAuxComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminListComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'other',
    component: AdminOtherComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    loadChildren: 'app/users/users.module#UsersModule',
  },
];
```

`users/users-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    outlet: 'aux',
    component: UsersAuxComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserDetailsComponent,
  },
];
```

I've made a simple repository demonstrating the issue and cataloging some of the research I've done into the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/auxilary-outlets

EDIT:

I've ruled out the lazy-loaded modules as part of the problem so I've created a simpler repro.

Simpler repro:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/auxiliary-outlets-2